# How to call a function through a variable?

Tags: javascript

I have the below code,

```
function MyFunc(){}
var myFunc = new MyFunc();
myFunc();  // through TypeError this line,
```

How can I make it to work if I want to call the function through the variable?

Answer (score 6):

By doing `new MyFunc()`, you're treating `MyFunc` as a constructor and are creating an object with it. This is treating `MyFunc` as a class that you want an instance of. You just want to assign another variable to point to the function, so you don't want the `new` or the `()`.

You want to just set `var myFunc = MyFunc`, and then calling `myFunc()` will work.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects. To refer to the object, just use the function name. So if you just want to call `MyFunc` through the `myFunc` variable, just assign `MyFunc` to `myFunc`:

```
function MyFunc(){}
var myFunc = MyFunc; // <=== Change on this line
myFunc();
```

Your original line:

```
var myFunc = new MyFunc();
```

...calls `MyFunc` as a constructor function, and `myFunc` (the variable) will receive a reference to whatever object is created as a result. (Just like, say, `var now = new Date();` creates a `Date` object and assigns it to `now`.)

Comment: So can you explain a little more about `var myFunc = MyFunc()`, what object does this line create?

Comment: That executes the function `MyFunc()` and assigns the return result from the function to the `myFunc` variable just like `var el = document.getElementById("header");` would.

Comment: @jfriend00, but there is no return statement in the function of MyFunc(), does this mean myFunc will receive a null pointer?

Comment: @Thomson: Did you mean `var myFunc = new MyFunc();`? When you call a function via `new`, the JavaScript engine creates a blank object, assigns its prototype from `MyFunc.prototype`, and then calls `MyFunc` with `this` set to refer to the new object. In the normal course of things, `MyFunc` would use `this` to initialize some properties, and the result of the `new` expression would be the object that was created. (It's possible for `MyFunc` to cause the new object to be thrown away and make the result of the `new` expression refer to a different object, but that's both advanced and unusual.)

Comment: @Thomson: If `MyFunc` doesn't return a value, if you just call it (`x = MyFunc();`), `x` will receive `undefined` (not `null`). If you call it via `new` (`x = new MyFunc();`), `x` will receive a reference to the object created by `new` (see my overlapping comment above).

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, a function is just another variable.

```
function MyFunc(){}
```

is the same as

```
var MyFunc = function(){};
```

Thus this is also valid

```
function MyFunc(){}
var myfunc = MyFunc;
myfunc();
```

Comment: *"...is the same as..."* No, it isn't. There are substantial differences between the first, which is a function declaration, and the second, which is a function expression. They're valid in different places syntactically, they're processed at different times, and they have different effects on the scope in which they're located.

Answer (score 1):

you create the object of the function the new keyword was used to create the object

```
var myfun_var = function MyFunc(){
       alert("hello");
}

and call myfun_var();
```

Answer (score 1):

So calling `new MyFunc()` will excute whatever code you put in there - it acts somewhat like a constructor in other languages - although not exactly.

If it wasn't a typo and you wanted to define a function on your class called myFunc if you wanted by doing something like

```
MyFunc.prototype.myFunc = function() {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you wanted is this:

```
var myFunc = function(){
    ....
};

myFunc();
```

This creates a variable named `myFunc` which is a reference to the anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/dWpEz/

```
var myFunc = function (){ alert("YES"); }
myFunc();
```

Answer (score -2):

The case doesn't match. Javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: Do you mean myFunc, I want to call the function through variable myFunc, not calling MyFunc directly.